# toLocaleString() show different result

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm using `.toLocaleString('it')` to convert a number from `12345` to `12.345` 
 becouse I need a point separator from thousands.

in JS it for as well

```
let number = 12345;
console.log(parseFloat(number).toLocaleString('it')) // Result: 12.345
```

but in pug I get a comma separator

```
#{parseFloat(data.number).toLocaleString('it')} 
// 12,345 <---- here must be 12.345
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this: https://codepen.io/bladeski/pen/QWpXdLL - can you confirm you are having issues still?

Comment: the issue is in Pug file

Comment: Can you share more of your code so that we can try and reproduce and see the problem? As I say, the CodePen above works fine - there may be something else in the code that is causing the problems.